# Css :hover not working on safari and ios always showing border

Tags: html, css

Hihi, I'm sure this is an error from webkit or simething like this but I wasn't able to fix it.

I have my development done with React and Sass as dendendency,
When I try to run the app in google chorme everything seems normal but when using safari or iOS (ipad or iphone) the :hover for example is not working and it's always underlineing the  tag

```
a {
  text-decoration: underline rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-underline-offset: 2px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  transition: text-decoration-color 300ms;
}

a:hover {
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: $black;
  text-decoration-color: $black;
}
```

[image: safari]

Answer (score 0):

try adding **-webkit-text-decoration**

```css
a {
  -webkit-text-decoration: underline rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-decoration: underline rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  text-underline-offset: 2px;
  text-decoration-thickness: 3px;
  transition: text-decoration-color 300ms;
}

a:hover {
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: black;
  text-decoration-color: black;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Test Link</a>
```

Comment: now the hover is working but the underline remains there, like it's doing the effect but not fade in out when "remove" the hover

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I'm facing the same thing with safari not changing the underline color activated by hover even when cursor is not hovering anymore